# Can not resolve symbol 'GravityCompat'

Tags: java, android, menu

I am fairly new to android and am facing some issues. Namely, android studio can not resolve symbol 'GravityCompat'.

I do import it in the beginning of my class:

```
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
```

Also added the support to my build.gradle (app):

```
 //Glide image library
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
```

The GravityCompat is used in my onBackPressed method:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            return;
        }
```

There are no other errors in my code. And I can't find an answer on the internet. Also, the GravityCompat is a library. I would not like to program myself. The same code does not give an error in a previous version of the same project.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: In a scrap project, I just added `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'`, and I have no problems referring to `GravityCompat`. The latest version of the support libraries is 25.0.1, and you may want to move to that version anyway, so try that and see if the problem clears up. If not, if you have not done so already, run Build > Clean Project from the Android Studio main menu.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your reply! I did clean the project before. But it did not fix anything. I thought it would be smart to first program my mainactivity (=loginscreen with signup option). It works fully. But didn't manage to program the menu. Therefore, used the navigationdrawer to program the Menu. When doing this, I didn't have issues with the GravityCompat. At this point, the gradle contained same compile line. Any other solutions than the scrap project?

Comment: Other than a typo somewhere, I cannot explain your symptoms -- sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble.

So, I checked my code again. Nothing was underlined. But I found my misspell in the `build.gradle(project)` in the raw:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31".
```

Misspelled was `classpath "..."` insted of `classpath '...'`.

It was result of changing of version `kotlin-gradle-plugin` by me.